# converting a mutex solution into a channel solution

Tags: go, channel

I am writing a golang program that has to perform multiple download requests at a time utilizing goroutines running in parallel (using GOMAXPROCS). In addition, there is a form of state kept, which is which components have been downloaded and which components are left to be downloaded. The mutex solution would be to lock this structure keeping track of which components have been successfully downloaded. I have read that when attempting to keep state, mutexes are the best option.

However, I am wondering what would be a solution utilizing channels (passing ownership instead of providing exclusive access to state) instead of mutexes, or are mutexes the best option?

P.S. 
So far I have thought of passing the global structure keeping state between go routines which are all utilizing one channel (a read-write channel). A go routine attempts to read the structure from the channel and then write it back when it's done.The problem I found with this, is that when the last running go routine [assume all others have finished and stopped running] gives up its posession of the structure by writing to the channel, it will result in deadlock since there are no receivers. In addition, this is still attempting to use channels as mutexes [attempting to provide exclusive access].

Comment: When you want "mutual exclusion" around a resource, use a mutex. There's no reason for a more complex solution with more concurrency, when a simple lock will do.

Comment: Roughly: a single goroutine acts as a "server", and "requests" are sent to it and "responses" sent back via channels--"requests" can include a struct with the response channel itself as a member. Agree with JimB you essentially never want to do that, though, but assigning all state a single "owner" is basically how you get from locks to CSP.

Comment: So then what is the difference between "passing ownership" and mutual exclusion? because the situation you both provided with the "server" and making requests sounds like passing ownership and also sounds like mutual exclusion.

Comment: Often, the usefulness of "passing ownership" is that you can describe the your app's data flow and your mutual-exclusion scheme at once using channel notation. If you want to do something like a work queue or pipeline, channels fit more naturally than mutexes. They're not terribly useful in the situation you're describing, as noted in the question and the comments above.

Comment: While I think the mutex is the right approach. If you have one lock object and you want sending it on a channel to have the semantics of releasing the lock, I think you could represent this with a buffered channel of size 1. Of course this will give you another problem where some other misbehaving code could push two values onto your channel. You should just use a mutex.